# Turning four vectors in to a shapefile with R

Tags: r, shapefile, qgis

I have four vectors in a CSV file. It looks similar to

```
Link StartX StartY EndX EndY
AA    1123   4445   666  888
BB     996    225   859  458
CC      ..     ..    ..   .. 
DD      ..     ..    ..   ..
..
.
.
i:2498
```

Each row corresponds to a segment. When the coordinates are plotted it appears as map as most segments have a connecting segment.

Any hints on how I could turn this into a shape file?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using R